# HTTPModule as ajax handler (IIS7+)

Tags: asp.net, ajax, performance, httpmodule

i have an argument at work about the best way to implement ajax handling for forms. we build all our forms under asp.net platform (sharepoint to be exact) but since we talk about public sites we though to cut the time-costing postbacks and make all postback in ajax request.

in order to best implement the server side i took a bit deeper look into handlers and modules and i then thought that i can cut all that by implementing a module that in his beginRequest identifies if its an ajax request (say by a special element in the querystring), and if so call CompleteRequest() and then in this module's endRequest if it was our ajax (say i flagged it in beginRequest) handle it.

so i would like to hear your thoughts about the pro's and con's about it, and also how "dangerously" it can impact the entire website ect.

the other option is, o.c., a generic handler (ajaxHandler.ashx).

i am again stating we are talking about IIS7+ where they integrated the pipelines.

p.s.
another thought is to build a WCF that will have to "open" (create instances) of anything that i would already have in my handler/module (in sharepoint for example the SPContext)

regards

Bresleveloper

Comment: Have you considered using WebMethods? You can call them fairly easily from ajax and you can keep using your current webforms logic

Comment: i have not and for 2 reasons. although in a simple app that could pretty much do the work, in a larger app i would like something more dynamic, more generic, and even with a load handler replacing the binding and validations of the asp.net controls by using pure html. the second more private reason is that i develop under sharepoint so i cant use webmethods as easy as in an asp.net solution.

Comment: MVC JSON Results can be used in Sharepoint?

Comment: even if i could (and i am pretty sure that with enough effort i could) the Q stays the same, should i implement it in a handler or a module